# Draft an article in REST

Tags: rest, restful-architecture, restful-url

In our system an article(title, description) can be created, updated an drafted.

- create - put
- update - post
- draft - ???

How to draft an article in REST?

Comment: I seems you have to use post too, but please  add more details so we can help more

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your REST api uses for example JSON, you could just have a `draft` flag on the article that can be `true` or `false`. Or a `published` flag that is `true` or `false`.

Answer (score 2):

As @Evert said, you can just use an attribute on the resource itself.

Or you could make the draft into a separate resource, which you can create, update and delete. When you promote the draft into an article, you could have the GET on that resource return an `HTTP 301 Moved permanently`.

It kind of depends on what workflow you want to support.

Comment: In case when draft promote to article, what it will be, update?

Comment: @leciro are you asking how to promote a draft to an article? Yes, I'd imagine that would either be a PUT or POST to the resource.

Comment: put - create a draft, post - update a draft, so how it will be to promote? to add a flag on update?

Comment: It would depend on your database representation of the resource, but a state field on your resource would be an obvious way to do this.